# The MSB (most significant bit ) in pyserial python sent to arduino uno in damged

Tags: python, python-2.7, arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno

Im trying to send a simple bits from python serial port to arduino uno.

```
import time
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(
    port=5,
    baudrate=9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
    bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
)
out=''
input=119
input= chr(input)
ser.write(input)
while ser.inWaiting() > 0: # reading input from the serial port
        out += ser.readline()
if out != '':
print "output from arduino is:" + out# printing the output from the serial port
```

In the Arduino the code is like this:

```
void serialEvent()  // called every time a command is recieved on the serial port
{
unsigned char input;
input= Serial.read();
Serial.println(input,BIN);
}
```

the binary representation for 119 is : 01110111 
The output from this line of code is-11110111
so it seems that arduino some how changing the MST bit (the 8 bit) from 0 to 1.
Any idea why? is it because Unicode or encode? Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is an [Arduino Stack Exchange](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/) you'll have better luck asking there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
```

…would suggest that you can only send 7-bit bytes, so the 8th bit is being added by the Arduino.

Simply discard the 8th bit in your Arduino code and you're good to go.